# Specflow designer generated code is using old specFlow 1.9.0.77

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, specflow

I have the following Nuget packages in my project.
Specflow v2.4.1
Nunit v3.11
Nunit Test Adapter v3.12

When I added or modified a feature file, specFlow is creating/modifying designer generated file somehow referring to old version of specFlow.

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;   

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("TechTalk.SpecFlow", "1.9.0.77")]
```

With this I am getting build errors and tests no longer running.

When checking the issue, I noticed that the TestTalk.SpecFlow.dll is pointing to bin/debug folder. When I closed the solution and removed all files from bin/debug folder then the reference path changed to packages folder and then the designer generated code is picking right specflow version.

The problem is re-occurring after build solution action is performed (Now Techtalk.specFlow.dll is referring to bin/debug folder)

I have tried to remove the designer generated code and run the custom tool again but only when the DLL is removed from bin/debug folder the problem resolved.

I even tried to change the setting Code Behind File Generation to AppDomain or Out of process but the issue persists.

Pls help to resolve the issue instead of deleting the files everytime. Thanks.

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back. I don't remember exactly how I fixed it, but I had multiple versions of SpecFlow in the packages folder for my Test project. I had to delete all the specflow packages except the newest specflow version I had specified in packages.config.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downgrading both NUnit and SpecFlow.

•   Nunit.Framework: 3.4.1
•   SpecFlow: 2.3.2